# OAuth 2.0 Access Tokens and Client Certificate

Tags: java, spring-boot, certificate, httprequest, token

So I'm currently developing a Spring boot MS that needs to connect to an external API which has OAuth 2.0 implemented.

The API Store uses a custom version of a grant type called a **Client Certificate**.

This grant type uses a combination of Mutual SSL and Application level credentials.

It requires two identity factors:

- Identity Factor 1 – Mutual SSL: Certificate created by me signed by the API store owner
- Identity Factor 2 – Application Level Credentials: {consumerKey:consumerSecret}

The curl command for obtaining this token is:

`curl -k -d "grant_type=client_cert" --basic -u "{consumer key}:{consumer secret}" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --cert {Certificate Pem} https://api.examplestore.com/token`

How can I translate this to my Spring boot application?

I've currently written this piece of code, but I think I'm far off.

```
public void TokenRequest() {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    String credentials = String.format("%s:%s", consumerKey, consumerSecret);
    String encodedCredentials = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(credentials.getBytes()));


    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    //headers.setCertificate??

    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

    response = restTemplate.exchange(tokenUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);

}
```

Any help is welcome. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not that far off.

You defenitely need to include the body:

```
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>("grant_type=client_cert", headers);
```

Also you need to include the certificate, maybe like this:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
    .loadTrustMaterial(new URL("/path/to/your/cert"), "certpassword".toCharArray())    
    .setProtocol("yourProtocol")
    .build();
 
final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
        .setSSLContext(sslContext)
        .build();

    final ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
        new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

...
```

Comment: That was helpful however I'm still wondering, don't I need a way to insert my private key file?

Comment: Okay I got it. I need to first convert  both my key and certificate to a p12 format, and then again to .PEM.  Like this `openssl pkcs12 -export -out abc_test.p12 -inkey abc_test.key -in abc_test.cer -name "abctest" -passout pass:yourpass` and then `openssl pkcs12 -in abc_test.p12 -out abc_test.pem -nodes`